# how to add multiple packages to build debian-live using live-wrapper

Tags: debootstrap, live-build

The only manual I could find is [readthedocs](http://live-wrapper.readthedocs.io). So far I have understood the following:

1. I have to start working in a dedicated directory
2. It needs the latest `debian-archive-keyring` not necessarily provided by other debian based OS
3. `-d` is distro `-m` is mirror server `-e` is package to be installed with only dependencies `-t` is package installed with recommendations and `-f` is installed firmware packages

Did I get it right?

Also I couldn't pass more then one package in either of the parameters. Could anyone lead me to the right direction?

My command so far goes like this:

```
lwr -d bullseye -m http://mirror.xeonbd.com/debian/ -e kde-full -t debian-installer-launcher -f firmware-realtek
```

I haven't used either `live-wrapper` or `live-build` before.

Comment: Welcome, your title doesn't match much with your question. It seems that the official docs are those pointed by you. But then you ask how to interpret said docs and how to run a command properly. It would be better that you fix the title to be more in line with the body of your question.

Comment: To find more information, you can try `man lwr`.

Comment: `$ man lwr -> No manual entry for lwr`